Exchange claiming they do not received my stellar after entering the wrong tag, how can I get it back?
back in July some stellars were sent to me but with the wrong tag, the source wallet(coinbase) saids that can not do anything since they are not in their network anymore and the recipent(Bitso) claim that they did not get them since the tag was wrong, any idea how to get them back?
